# How to get each web user's status is online or offline on server side ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> when user was close the tab or browser means that user can't online so i want to manage some status using that Online or offline status.

How to do get status please get the solution.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please show your code.

Comment: Start by clearly defining what you mean exactly when you say a user is "online", and remember that a server cannot look at the user's screen to see if a tab is open. All the server has to go by is requests received from the browser.

Comment: You could use ajax polling to send the server a "I'm alive" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when user was close the tab or browser means that user can't online so
>   i want to manage some status using that Online or offline status.

You can get hold of the close event `window.onbeforeunload` of the tab or Browser. And within this event execute a ajax call to server by passing the userId, Then in server you will just have to update your DB to say the user is offline.

Example of how to catch the close event, [**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/3dxbs8vp/)

**JavaScript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    //your ajax call to server
};
```

**Jquery**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  //your ajax call to server
});
```

implementing Ajax call in [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and in [Jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Example of your ActionResult in server,

```
public ActionResult SignOutUser(string userId){
  // your code to log off the user (either expire his cookies or log offline status in db)
}
```

This is the basic Idea of how such scenarios are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an authentication system you can add a new column to your person/account table with a datetime value. Here you can store a timestamp when the user was last active. You can update this field by using a middleware. So whenever a user request a new page you can then update the timestamp in your database. To decide if the user is online you have to take a range in seconds that you assume a user is online, like if the user requested a page 10, 20 , 30  seconds ago you can assume the user is online.